# Django Many to Many Relationship With Another Field

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models, `Recipe` and `Ingredient`. The Recipe model has a manytomany relationship with Ingredients, but I also need to be able to specify the quantity of the ingredients. My models currently look like:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="256", db_index=True, null=True)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    ...
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, related_name="RecipeIngredients", db_index=True)
```

But obviously each recipe will have different quantities of each ingredient. So I need to be able to do something like:

```
cakeRecipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=1)
flour = Ingredient.objects.get(pk=2)
cakeRecipe.ingredients.add(flour, '200 grams')
```

But I don't know how. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow the instructions on [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

```
class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe')
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey('Ingredient')
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through=RecipeIngredient)
```

Comment: The link in your comment returns a 404.  It should be https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 2):

You want an intermediatery model. As in - some model that will link between the two, using the 'through' argument. Like so:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="256", db_index=True, null=True)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    ...
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, 
                                         related_name="RecipeIngredients", 
                                         db_index=True,
                                         through='Quantity')


class Quantity(models.Model):
    ingrediant = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    #... any other fields ...
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).