# Efficient way in Django Models to store Items Purchased in a Transaction for a Commerce Store

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

I've created two simple Django Models. 
One model simply holds the bill details.
The other one holds the list of items purchased in that Bill, linked through a foreign key relation.
I'm stuck at a problem of creating a very large database with this implementation.
Model Classes :

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    seller_id = models.ForeignKey(User , related_name = 'bill')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 7 , decimal_places = 2)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(User , related_name = 'bill')
```

and

```
class BillItems(models.Model):
    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill , related_name = 'items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product , related_name = 'items')
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6 , decimal_places = 3)
```

Now as I see it , after some time my database(**MySql**) would have a very large number of **Bill Items'** instances. 
Is there a better way to implement such a structure?
OR
Is there a way to optimize this structure?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: your amount field in the Bill model is redundant if it is just storing the total number of items purchased in a bill. you can get that by taking a sum of all the quantity from BillItems for a bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't think it's that big of a problem (it will at worst have x10 records than Bills table, which in DB world is not that big of a deal).
- But if you have to, a better way would be to have a many to many relationship between Bills and Product. The only issue will be adding "quantity" to your bridge table. You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279585/3802821) answer on how to implement it.